# Passing ?input map as Datomic query argument

Tags: database, clojure, datomic

How to pass a map as `?input` to a Datomic query and destructure the map for matching against facts?

When I run the following query, I get a `NullPointerException`:

```
(d/q '[:find ?e
       :where
       :in $ ?input
       [?e :amount ?amount]
       [(:amount ?input) ?amount]]
     (d/db conn)
     {:amount 123.0M})
=> Syntax error (NullPointerException) compiling at ...
```

However, passing the amount as an input argument, works:

```
(d/q '[:find ?e
       :where
       :in $ ?amount
       [?e :amount ?amount]
     (d/db conn)
     123.0M)
=> [[1234]]
```

Comment: Perhaps you just have to do the destructuring outside of Datomic, as in your working example

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a map into a Datalog query, you're limited to scalars, tuples, collections and relations:

[Datomic Query Bindings](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query.html#bindings)

If you had a much more complex map than your example and needed to use many values from it, you'd have to destructure it outside (as @Alan Thompson suggested) the query and pass the values in as a tuple:

```clj
(let [input-fn (juxt :amount :timestamp :quantity)
      input-data {:timestamp "29/08/2019" :quantity 3 :amount 123.0}
      inputs (input-fn input-data)]
  (d/q '[:find ?e
         :in $ [?amount ?timestamp ?quantity]
         :where
         [?e :amount ?amount]
         [?e :timestamp ?timestamp]
         [?e :quantity ?quantity]]
    (d/db conn)
    inputs))
```